# При каком наименьшем n число конечных частей может оказаться больше, чем число бесконечных?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

На плоскости проводят n прямых, делящих плоскость на некоторое число конечных и бесконечных частей.

Мне кажется , что нужно посчитать количество конечных и бесконечных областей. Бесконечных 2n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут все более-менее просто. При разрезании n прямыми получается всего - всех - n(n+1)/2 + 1 частей (см., например, [тут](https://oeis.org/A000124)).

Из них - 2n бесконечных. Значит, надо, чтоб n(n+1)/2+1 -2n > 2n, откуда n >= 7...

При этом всего частей 29, бесконечных - 14, конечных - 15...

Comment: откуда вы взяли что их 29?
"n(n+1)/2 + 1 частей" это формула откуда?

Comment: а я думаю что ответ 3. Проводим 3 параллельные прямые. Дальше в геометрии Лобачевского имеем 2 конечные области и 1 внешнюю :D

Comment: Выводить мне лень, но это не так уж и сложно - в любой популярной комбинаторике должно быть. Я дал ссылку на готовую формулу - вы по ней переходили?

Comment: @Harry а откуда 29 вы взяли?

Comment: Медленно и печально: семь плюс один дает восемь. Семь, умноженное на восемь, дает пятьдесят шесть. Пятьдесят шесть, деленное на два, дает двадцать восемь. Прибавить к двадцати восьми один - получается 29...

Comment: *При разрезании n прямыми получается всего - всех - n(n+1)/2 + 1 частей* Это ошибочное утверждение. Формула даёт МАКСИМАЛЬНО ВОЗМОЖНОЕ количество областей - но их может быть меньше, если 1) есть параллельные (в т.ч. совпадающие); 2) есть три и более прямых, пересекающихся в одной точке.

Comment: @Akina Но при этом вы не получите **наименьшее** n, о котором говорится в условии.

Comment: Вообще-то это обоснование является важной частью решения - задача-то явно учебная. Я бы как преподаватель без явного указания на этот момент отправил бы гулять с формулировкой "неполное обоснование решения".

Comment: @Akina Вероятно, для меня это кажется само собой разумеющимся, потому что я не преподаватель... :)

Comment: @Akina так как правильно сформулировать решение?

Comment: я бы просто нарисовал)) Что не меньше 7 доказано. Осталось пример привести.

Comment: @pavel *Что не меньше 7 доказано* Нет. Ибо количество и открытых, и замкнутых областей может быть меньше расчётного максимального количества. И нужно либо доказать, что описанные выше случаи уменьшают количество закрытых областей быстрее (или хотя бы не медленнее) количества открытых, либо выполнить полный перебор всех вариантов с 1-6 прямыми.

Comment: @Akina  можете тогда дать свое решение?

Comment: @gaak2309 Рассмотреть обе трансформации (смещение одной прямой на точку пересечения двух других, и поворот одной прямой так, что она становится параллельна другой) и показать, как именно каждая из них изменяет количество закрытых и открытых областей.

Comment: @Akina Открытых - не изменяет никак, если есть хотя бы одна прямая, пересекающая все остальные параллельные, то 2n. Если все параллельные - нет ни одной конечной области - не наш случай. Осталось найти случай, когда всяческих областей получится как можно больше - а это только тогда, когда все прямые пересекаются в разных точках (достаточно рассмотреть пересечение трех прямых в одной точке и потом их растащить... Все. Дальше - наша формула для количества частей, и больше ничего не нужно. Нет?

Comment: *Открытых - не изменяет никак, если есть хотя бы одна прямая, пересекающая все остальные параллельные, то 2n.* Две пересекающиеся прямые - 4 открытые области. 2 параллельные - 3 области. Не изменяет, да?

Comment: @Akina Еще раз и медленно... **не изменяет никак, если есть хотя бы одна прямая, пересекающая все остальные параллельные**. Ваш контрпример - 2 параллельные. Где здесь хотя бы одна прямая, которая пересекает другую?

Comment: @Akina я решил)решение сейчас выставлю

Comment: @Harry я сейчас свое еще решение добавлю))только оно полное)

Comment: @Akina добавил второе решение)

Comment: @Harry добавил второе решение) только более грамотное

Comment: @pavel решил посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Прямая - это бесконечная штука. Можно считать, что каждая прямая пересекается с каждой - параллельные прямые вообще не могут образовывать конечных кусков. Так вот, точек пересечения будет конечное число. Представьте себе очень большой круг так, чтобы все точки пересечения попали внутрь его. n прямых выходит из этого круга, и каждая прямая создаёт 2 бесконечные части, разбивая плоскость на 2 полуплоскости.

Теперь с конечными частями. Их мы получим просто - вычитанием бесконечных частей из общих.

k-я прямая пересекает k-1 предыдущую прямую и добавляет k частей.

Первая прямая даёт 2 области.

Поэтому всего у нас будет на n прямых n*(n+1)*/2 + 1 часть. Из них бесконечных 2n и конечных (n-1)*(n-2)/2.

Ну и подставляете :

На 6: 5*4/2 = 10, 6*2 = 12

На 7: 6*5/2 =15, 7*2 = 14.

**Ответ: n=7**

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у нас n прямых. Если они общего положения (то есть никакие 3 не пересекаются в одной точке и никакие 2 не параллельны), то всего образуется 1 + n (n + 1) / 2 частей. Это получается по индукции, каждая добавленная прямая к данным n делит (n + 1) часть на две. Если прямые не общего положения, то количество частей может только уменьшиться (что следует из той же индукции).

Случай, когда все прямые параллельны, нам не подходит. Заметим, что иначе n прямых создают 2n бесконечных частей, потому что любая достаточно большая окружность (для которой все точки пересечения прямых находятся внутри круга) разбивается этими прямыми на 2n дуг, и эти дуги объективно соответствуют бесконечным частям.

Количество конечных частей не больше 1 + n (n + 1) / 2 - 2n, и нам нужно, чтобы это было больше 2n (раз не все прямые параллельны друг другу). То есть достаточно рассматривать прямые только в общем положении и ответ — это наименьшее натуральное решение неравенства 1 + n (n + 1) / 2 > 4n. Преобразуем:

2 + n^2 + n > 8n

n^2 - 7n + 2 > 0

n > (7 + sqrt(41)) / 2

n >= 7.

Ответ: 7 прямых.